# Error when reading sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to read a .mtx file in R that has a symmetric sparse matrix. I'm using the e1071 package and the following command:

```
read.matrix.csr("filename.mtx")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error in rja[, 2] : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In read.matrix.csr("soc-twitter-follows.mtx") : NAs introduced by coercion

I tried other .mtx files but I keep getting the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your mtx files are really in the csr format?

I get the same error as you if I try to open a mtx file from the Matrix package using e1071's read.matrix.csr.

However, I can open that file with Matrix::readMM, then save it with write.matrix.csr (from Matrix).  At that point, I know I have a valid csr file, which can indeed be opened with e1071::read.matrix.csr.

```
library(Matrix)
library(e1071)

e1071::read.matrix.csr(system.file("external/pores_1.mtx", package = "Matrix"))

pores <-
  Matrix::readMM(system.file("external/pores_1.mtx", package = "Matrix"))

write.matrix.csr(x = pores, file = 'pores.csr')

from.csr <- e1071::read.matrix.csr('pores.csr')
```